# How to play YouTube video list in chronological order?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Here's a random YouTube video list sorted in chronological order:

https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile/videos?sort=da&flow=list&view=0

If you click on the <kbd>PLAY ALL</kbd> button, however, the order of the playback does not match the chronological ordering of the original list.

Is there a way to play the list back in chronological order?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that since downloading from YouTube is against their ToS, it's also against this site's ToS.

Comment: @arieljannai: thanks for the pointer; I've modified my question accordingly.

Comment: Note you're linking to a video list of a user, not to a playlist

Comment: @arieljannai: I've reworded my post; what should I fix next?

Comment: Looks better - good luck! hope you'll find an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like YouTube doesn't support it, but it can be done:

first, you need to get all **ID**s from that sorted range (I copy/pasted source code into google spreadsheet and filtered it out)

```
Muc5HQonSEo
sPFWfAxIiwg
umYvFdU54Po
mLQNvuZH3GU
ZfKTD5lvToE
d8TRcZklX_Q
kw6l_uTakRA
fUSZBVYZdKY
4aMtJ-V26Z4
PLL0mo5rHhk
mhJY74Bw8mw
9xbJ3enqLnA
hiOMtBrH8pc
MlyTq-xVkQE
5sKah3pJnHI
IQofiPqhJ_s
bFfSfzjhfC8
kC6YObu61_w
a2ey9a70yY0
8GEebx72-qs
_DpzAvb3Vk4
LzjaDKVC4iY
-O4mYiP2zPQ
DRxAVA6gYMM
daro6K6mym8
D6tINlNluuY
abv4Fz7oNr0
sJVivjuMfWA
yJ-HwrOpIps
wPn4tgmU8ek
QTrM-UVcgBY
U7f8j3mVMbc
UfEiJJGv4CE
XTeJ64KD5cg
DRjFV_DETKQ
UkZqFtYtqaI
CMUI6m8ZMwg
ci3P5jf48cY
RxxDD2LWAyY
R9m2jck1f90
C-52AI_ojyQ
kUBIJdGsD1A
1EGDCh75SpQ
4mEk7d8oRho
yu_aqA7mw7E
MmhNk-zRJcU
8d49sEAU5Ws
oIkhgagvrjI
KbxRDVCVzq4
elvOZm0d4H0
euAHY9hqRN4
mqK63v2Jzks
nBgQPSUTWVM
1GCf29FPM4k
p_Hqdqe84Uc
fiTwar7mFws
A25pxcYstHM
M-yAgyrzGdo
f2Gne3UHKHs
x6Ml4AEt0kk
tflf05x-WVI
dXGhzY2p2ug
Dd81F6-Ar_0
dHzUQnRjbuM
pT52hREAf18
EDauz38xV9w
-Djj6pfR9KU
8542XmS98Yo
yF2J39Xny4Q
QV9k6dRQQe4
tivvYl8ZRvA
BTyzE-NDga8
kQZmZRE0cQY
ZDn_DDsBWws
vNTSugyS038
RkBl7WKzzRw
2dzS_LXvYA0
BRRolKTlF6Q
3ZMnVd4ivKQ
ygqIfLHGTu4
gVzu1_12FUc
83ofi_L6eAo
uuMwz47LV_w
Cn3ogzLzxuM
aiibxmqXV9M
xYAU75IS40A
l7lP9y7Bb5g
VpBmt11czaI
8t1TC-5OLdM
M7kEpw1tn50
U6xJfP7-HCc
ZPv1UV0rD8U
uak-wvXJAvE
mlqAvhjxAjo
G2_Q9FoD-oQ
V4V2bpZlqx8
XXjlR2OK1kM
VbtNy54ya9A
n3x8fIdsla4
QJQ691PTKsA
-rwqnVsGFTU
wCyC-K_PnRY
QSEKzFGpCQs
YJuHC7xXsGA
a9P9Ej1b31s
FpyrF_Ci2TQ
NajQEiKFom4
iW_LkYiuTKE
SzjdcPbjaR4
ZNiRzZ66YN0
bFNjA9LOPsg
x4kyFKyCMv0
QzrRkhU248A
WM1FFhaWj9w
GyN-qpVfOWA
CMP9a2J4Bqw
Waw11zhaKSk
e4sF_Z5oJek
u7Z9UnWOJNY
SxP30euw3-0
noDSyLzVz2g
ctC33JAV4FI
XvDC-0aNw2k
wo19Y4tw0l8
JJQWtGm3eIs
Fmb3TCvlETk
gaVMrqzb91w
5JOAoiX1LHA
vkMXdShDdtY
D4_sNKoO-RA
u17MdWjGA5I
nd_Z_jZdzP4
acTrvMlpuxA
Mfk_L4Nx2ZI
seUU2bZtfgM
dzerDfN2E7U
SbZCECvoaTA
j7jfHM-mMC4
PCu_BNNI5x4
iFuR97YcSLM
3K-12i0jclM
dDl7g_2x74Q
VDD6FDhKCYA
YBbBbY4qvv4
JmyLeESQWGw
aIggWlKr41w
l8ezziaEeNE
N7BABxMlOs0
VRzH4xB0GdM
8UqCyepX3AI
Nu-lW-Ifyec
qiNcEguuFSA
CfoKor05k1I
eaJtjJNrWf0
_YysNM2JoFo
WUlaUalgxqI
K305Vu7hFg0
cUCSSJwO3GU
yDWPi1pZ0Po
kOClr_bew38
lFQGSGsXbXE
qbkH_0TNdk0
1O69uBL22nY
6aDBGTWsydY
NPoj8lk9Fo4
w-I6XTVZXww
ab_dY3dZFHM
Yexc19j3TjE
3_VydFQmtZ8
jbiaz_aHHUQ
HvMSRWTE2mI
y8acoaakvPM
vzV50goW_WM
E8kUJL04ELA
d6c6uIyieoo
E36qMxXGo3A
TUErNWBOkUM
0Oazb7IWzbA
09JslnY7W_k
7dcDuVyzb8Y
3T7jMcstxY0
lNuPy-r1GuQ
iwo7JReFTeg
sG_6nlMZ8f4
hwOCqA9Xw6A
GItmC9lxeco
CwIAfkuXc5A
LBPj8E1JKaQ
00Qu1kgsGpM
ItiFO5y36kw
xOCe5HUObD4
4Lb-6rxZxx0
7u6kFlWZOWg
xdiL-ADRTxQ
8l-La9HEUIU
wBU9N35ZHIw
sxLdGjV-_yg
ZWib5olGbQ0
xPk3SZiFEvQ
shEk8sz1oOw
HX8bihEe3nA
GuigptwlVHo
NGMRB4O922I
txajrEOTkuY
eZUa5k_VIZg
ea7lJkEhytA
4UgZ5FqdYIQ
OuF-WB7mD6k
ZkVSRwFWjy0
HuKl3XuEmj4
Qcv1IqHWAzg
OEMA6jhi5Qo
I7v2wAXFQpc
m5evLoL0xwg
D8ntDpBm6Ok
dTWKKvlZB08
PeUbRXnbmms
n_FsAwvxBI8
0r3cEKZiLmg
99Welatppzk
Lsu2dIr_c8k
mX0NB9IyYpU
izdZPx89ph4
IMItxzSZs0E
6Lm9EHhbJAY
SL2lYcggGpc
v678Em6qyzk
q8n15q1v4Xo
T0xKHwQH-4I
E-d9mgo8FGk
KboGyIilP6k
yfr3BIk6KFc
rudzYPHuewc
Z8lv2vy5vco
AYnJv68T3MM
Obg7JPd6cmw
GznQgTdEdI4
87uo2TPrsl8
ZbKYmfjMPVM
9TAlEVDvXgw
_qvp9a1x2UM
l4bmZ1gRqCc
nUN4NDVIfVI
AxJubaijQbI
OfEv5ZdSrhY
Y2lXsxmBx7E
BkOIw7vAZCQ
PnW5IRvgvLY
_s5RFgd59ao
emiMj8cCL5E
U9qU20VmvaU
7c0CoXFApnM
gjVDqfUhXOY
u6Got0X41pY
ud_frfkt1t0
5qu3WETuf6c
l7E-pBWuSIA
0hlvhQZIOQw
LNS1fabDkeA
AAsICMPwGPY
-k3mVnRlQLU
2g3sdzgSABM
t2ZoU0LEM6E
99stb2mzspI
4KHCuXN2F3I
3WHBlPvK3Ek
Km024eldY1A
aqyyhhnGraw
M-i9v9VfCrs
JnEBO3OHaiA
jPcBU0Z2Hj8
PFkZGpN4wmM
WYijIV5JrKg
NWBToaXK5T0
vA2cdHLKYB8
ZREp1mAPKTM
d0vY0CKYhPY
pKwsPBeSiOc
j-dce6QmVAQ
Lihh_lMmcDw
AxxnziuL408
UkmQNbvlK8s
wymmCdLdPvM
I3ZlhxaT_Ko
wKV0GYvR2X8
mh3eMt09EAs
CN8hK3YFqhM
ktPvjr1tiKk
h09XU8t8eUM
HPfAnX5blO0
QAja2jp1VjE
XPIgR89jv3Q
xRpR1rmPbJE
vgZhrEs4tuk
3BR8tK-LuB0
tlpYjrbujG0
lEvXcTYqtKU
wVH4MS6v23U
lCjspXB5F4A
JuuYFt8bahE
8Nzi1h2m7pE
wwh0KH-ICCw
WYsP1PhoAZc
2s4TqVAbfz4
M8xlOm2wPAA
eAjMvpRMVDw
ua1K3Eo2PQc
aOT_bG-vWyg
aQxCnmhqZko
wGkvyN6s9cY
NjCIq58rZ8I
iObpxBfOLv4
YVvfY_lFUZ8
VTveQ1ndH1c
AEpQ8YxupfQ
y12Tt3bOmKA
Ra9I_-o2LHM
Vp3sgYKULp0
TkGawXjsltc
_-M_3oV75Lw
4izjrtR8Ozg
SDw2Pu0-H4g
5Mf0JpTI_gg
gi-TBlh44gY
mPn2AdMH7UQ
ovsYv-b-wWI
2JM2oImb9Qg
AOMQxLrCI7A
Sa9jLWKrX0c
siawhQBRC8I
MEyIppEOQTw
5mFpVDpKX70
QFeG9CeeH88
Y30VF3cSIYQ
63ILZ9cZ2d4
eeLpkCZkWfc
6_j2X6fgkaA
MfzNJE4CK_s
k8Rxep2Mkp8
G7zT9MljJ3Y
8UUPlImm0dM
zzKGnuvX6IQ
x-DgL49CFlM
4k1jegU4Wb4
tY69D3PSmIk
hP-DZMmQBng
uCsD3ZGzMgE
W18FDEA1jRQ
ZM-i8t4pMK0
BYRTvoZ3Rho
49KvZrioFB0
5kC5k5QBqcc
QvvkJT8myeI
8dHMpnfFdtc
AuA2EAgAegE
xgBGibfLD-U
djmec-Bweeg
1MtEUErz7Gg
ETrYE4MdoLQ
Gq4REVI30Qc
xopM9BFjcNo
YQw124CtvO0
Noo4lN-vSvw
D046q2EbHGE
PQDvEJFdY1U
xhj5er1k6GQ
Ku8BOBwD4hc
0iMtlus-afo
MXJ-zpJeY3E
NgbK43jB4rQ
rXfKWIZQIo4
LqKpkdRRLZw
4dUK1JqTSgU
QKHKD8bRAro
-ruC5A9EzzE
pasyRUj7UwM
kbKtFN71Lfs
ur-iLy4z3QE
WN58941sgtI
MxiTG96QOxw
PEMIxDjSRTQ
O4ndIDcDSGc
mccoBBf0VDM
NoRjwZomUK0
I0peG_kRE-4
3IMAUm2WY70
RhuaPhahHbU
ezdeBrPnzyc
m6rfpQXzXu0
lpj0E0a0mlU
BH1GMGDYndo
co5sOgZ3XcM
pbXg5EI5t4c
aCq04N9it8U
G_uybVKBacI
fQQ8IiTWHhg
FlndIiQa20o
EeuLDnOupCI
mceaM2_zQd8
kaMKInkV7Vs
7dwgusHjA0Y
4LQvjSf6SSw
9yUZTTLpDtk
3P6DWAwwViU
m3drS_8BpU0
4kWuxfVbIaU
fcVjitaM3LY
un-pTKfC1dQ
2BIx2x-Q2fE
A8Tiba3h9Fw
YCXmUi56rao
ZCVAGb1ee8A
G1m7goLCJDY
i3D7XYQExt0
5SfXqTENV_Q
p-xa-3V5KO8
wJGE4aEWc28
Us-__MukH9I
FtNWzlfEQgY
AvFNCNOyZeE
AZRD5UkAm2Y
mthPiiCS24A
3Bv-QMaYlmo
BDEo5XpZcXo
bPZFQ6i759g
aKPkQCys86c
wZ1E_CM7MqA
_pP_C7HEy3g
sj8Sg8qnjOg
7lRgeTmxnlg
1gBwexpG0IY
4445Mbw8pYg
hHG8io5qIU8
FGC5TdIiT9U
6H6EP-AmMFM
DhPtIf-hpuU
```

then just copy this list and paste it into http://roll.io/

press **<kbd>Run my list!</kbd>** button and you are good to watch

and as for downloading: [https://www.youtube.net/channel.php?id](https://www.genyoutube.net/channel.php?id=UCoxcjq-8xIDTYp3uz647V5A&sort=d)

---

**ADDITIONAL DETAILS:**

source code in a spreadsheet: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8Jjx1Db2Bacv7iXozNQ1gG3hBVtk7Xmo1WvZ9GtU9g/edit?usp=sharing)

chronologically sorted playlist: http://roll.io/#4U2pNU!0

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

## **DOWNLOAD IN CHRONOLOGICAL ORDER:**

- download this: https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl.exe
- extract IDs in this format: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8Jjx1Db2Bacv7iXozNQ1gG3hBVtk7Xmo1WvZ9GtU9g/edit#gid=2084478212)
- in folder where you downloaded **youtube-dl.exe** create text file named **feed.txt**
- copy whole **column A** from spreadsheet [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8Jjx1Db2Bacv7iXozNQ1gG3hBVtk7Xmo1WvZ9GtU9g/edit#gid=2084478212)
- paste it into **feed.txt**
- create batch file **BATCH.cmd** with content:
  **`youtube-dl.exe -o %(autonumber)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s -a feed.txt`**
- run/execute **BATCH.cmd** by double-clicking
- and wait till finished

this will download all video files in chronological order in format `00001-Title.mp4` etc. here are supported options: https://pastebin.com/raw/XGh82hg8 and there are more format options: https://pastebin.com/raw/fgqQbpRC also its possible to feed your desktop media player directly like: **`youtube-dl.exe -o - -a feed.txt | PotPlayerMini64.exe -`** 
and also there is a possibility to download all IDs with: 
**`youtube-dl.exe --get-id https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile/ > t.txt`** 
and ditch all that ID scraping from source code (note that then you need to open t.txt file with Word/Wordpad, because notepad will show it format-less in one string)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

## **PLAY ON YOUTUBE IN CHRONOLOGICAL ORDER:**

- get list of IDs either with **youtube-dl.exe** or from source code
- copy/paste it into google spreadsheet and create comma-separated list (ID,ID,ID...)
- you can use **`=JOIN(",";A1:A)`** (as shown in **[A1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8Jjx1Db2Bacv7iXozNQ1gG3hBVtk7Xmo1WvZ9GtU9g/edit#gid=1022026325)**)
- then add the **lead** to it: **`="https://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids="&A1`** (as shown in **[A4](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8Jjx1Db2Bacv7iXozNQ1gG3hBVtk7Xmo1WvZ9GtU9g/edit#gid=1022026325)**)
- copy cell **A4**, paste it into browser's search box and hit **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**
- this will create special playlist URL called "Untitled Playlist" where you will have chronologicaly sorted videos
   **`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Muc5HQonSEo&list=TLGGiqkpBaB_k8UwNTA3MjAxOA`**

**SIDE NOTE: unfortunately there is one downside... such playlist is limited only to 50 videos**

- to save such playlist, be sure that you are logged in into youtube
- add **&disable_polymer=true** at the end of the URL and hit **<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**
   **`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Muc5HQonSEo&list=TLGGiqkpBaB_k8UwNTA3MjAxOA&disable_polymer=true`**
- then, somewhere around **<kbd>Subscribe</kbd>** button will appear **<kbd>+ Add to</kbd>** button (or 3-dot/3-slash button with plus sign)
- select **Create a new playlist** name it and press **<kbd>Create</kbd>** button
- done!

there is also API approach, that can maybe handle 50+ videos (but that's not fun):
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert#examples
or also AHK (AutoHotKey - https://www.autohotkey.com/ ) script:

```
;;;Select youtube videos with clipboard to create a playlist. Use CTRL + Y when finished.

;Below allows script to start with clipboard empty
clipboard =   ; Empty the clipboard

;Define playlist string
playlist = http://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=

Msgbox Use clipboard to select videos. `nUse CNTL + Y when done selecting videos. `nCNTL + Z exits the script.

#Persistent
OnClipboardChange("ClipChanged")
return

ClipChanged(Type) {
if clipboard contains youtube.com/watch,youtube.com/embed/,youtu.be
    {
    StringRight, clipboard, clipboard, 11   ; Removes all but last 11 characters
    gosub, doit
    return
    } 
 return   
} 

doit:
    count++
    playlist = %playlist%%clipboard%,
    TrayTip, Current Playlist:, %playlist% `nNumber of Videos: %count%`nUse CNTL + Y when done selecting videos ...
    Sleep 2000
    TrayTip  ; Turn off the tip.
    return

^y:: 
;Remove last comma, display playlist, and copy playlist to clipboard
StringTrimRight, playlist2, playlist, 1 ;Replace last comma with blank (also converts the clipboard to plain text).
clipboard = %playlist2%
;Turn off OnClipboardChange
OnClipboardChange("ClipChanged", 0)
Msgbox Number of Videos in playlist: %count% `n%playlist2% `nPlaylist copied to clipboard `n`nUse CNTL + Z to exit ...
;Turn OnClipboardChange on again (necessary to keep Clipboard from aquiring playlist2)
OnClipboardChange("ClipChanged", 1)
return

^z:: 
ExitApp
```

## **EXTENSIONS TO EXTRACT URL LINKS:**

- add browser extension: **[firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/copy-urls-expert/)** / **[chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-links/kcpoommnneaebpfgaoejklgemonkmjpc)**
- select area with your mouse from where extension will extract all URL links
- after selecting area / text with right-click-mouse-drag, click on extension icon and perform desired operation

## **SPREADSHEET YOUTUBE PLAYLIST GENERATOR:**

here I wrote a simple spreadsheet playlist generator: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n8Jjx1Db2Bacv7iXozNQ1gG3hBVtk7Xmo1WvZ9GtU9g/edit#gid=1950325992)
 just add youtube links in any desired order and press that red text in cell **B1**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain how you got all those IDs?  The source code I get does not have anywhere near that many, not to mention the fact that the *tiny few* ones that are present need to be extracted from the mess of surrounding HTML...

Comment: @kjo well, I used source code of the last url from my answer after I loaded all sources with that "Load More..." button. then I copied upper div element that contains all sub-divs with IDs. pasted it into sheet. filtered out all rows that contains: vidbox" id=" ...then used find&replace to strip off everything from IDs. next I reversed IDs order and thats pretty much it.

Comment: @kjo added few pictures and sheet. fyi you can use YT source code as well and then filter for: null" href="/watch?v= ...but its less compact eg. it will give you 49800 initial rows instead of 9732 gentube source code rows

Comment: Thanks for the additional details.  I just wanted to point out that roll.io won't do; it's fine for music, but not for videos, since (AFAICT) it does not support full screen.  (More specifically, when I click on the full screen icon, a message pops ups saying "Full screen is unavailable".)

Comment: @kjo I see. it would require to add `allowFullScreen="allowFullScreen"` in every `<iframe>` to support fullscreen. anyway, I added "how to download in chronological order" part with some pictures

Comment: @kjo haha, last update (maybe) - added "how to play on youtube in chronological order" part, "how to use extensions to extract links from mouse selection" part and also "spreadsheet playlist generator" part

Comment: I'd like to start a new bounty, that I would automatically award to you, but for some reason I'm not given the option to start a new bounty.  I think this is because I don't have enough XP.  I'll work on this.  Apologies once more.

Comment: OK, I figured out a way to award you the bounty.  Basically, I put a bounty on another question that you answered, and will award it to you as soon as SE lets me.  (I don't understand why SE makes its users jump through so many hoops.)

Comment: @kjo thats weird. this should be automated. even mods are silent. shame :(

Comment: OK, done.  Thank you for your answer, and sorry for the nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

When you hit **Play All** button from the **All Videos** page, youtube always plays it in **Newest to Oldest** sort order. We just want the reverse of it!

Here's this extension - [Iridium](https://github.com/ParticleCore/Iridium), that does exactly the same.

Iridium (former YouTube Plus) is an extension built to improve the user experience on the new YouTube Material layout.

Simple Instructions (One Time):

- Install extensions from here: [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iridium/gbjmgndncjkjfcnpfhgidhbgokofegbl), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/particle-iridium/)
- Browse https://www.youtube.com/iridium-settings
- Select Video under left page
- Enable reverse playlist control
- You're done, reload the youtube-playlist-page.

Now you can sort playlist chronologically with this button:
 [image]

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this extension is not FLOSS, its license is neither libre nor open source. This is a deal breaker for me and I'd recommend against using this extension, in addition to the name being in conflict with a fork of chromium: https://iridiumbrowser.de/.

Comment: Furthermore, this does not work with playlists that are longer than 80 entries.