# YouTube playlist not in dark theme

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I've switched on a dark theme for YouTube, and all the pages I've gone to are in dark theme as far as I can see.

However, there's one particular playlist (unlisted if that matters) that is still in the old layout, and I notice the URL has this `&disable_polymer=true`.

Tried to change it to `&disable_polymer=false` and removing it completely but it just shows up again.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It can be useful if you'll share the playlist link, if possible

Answer (score 1):

that's standard behavior - YT still didn't implement new design on this. you can remove whole  **`&disable_polymer=true`** from URL which should bring you desired result.

**`&disable_polymer=true`** piece is there for the ability to save an unlisted playlist to your account eg. saving an unlisted playlist should also bring you desired result. more on this topic here: [How to play YouTube video list in chronological order?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/118377/how-to-play-youtube-video-list-in-chronological-order)