# Can you view your total upload hours on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, video, youtube-channel

I was trying to see how many hours of content I had uploaded to YouTube (preferably without counting it all by hand).

I was wondering if there was a way of viewing this. I looked through all the settings and couldn't find anything about the total length of *all* videos on my channel.

Google wasn't any help either, just directing me to results that talked about how much total videos were on the *whole of YouTube*

Does such an option exist? Or do I just have to add them up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can easily do so by using Google Sheets...
- to get individual duration per video:

  ```
  =SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(A2, "//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content"),
   "PT|S", ""), "M", ":0")
  ```
- to get total duration of all videos:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUOTIENT(SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\d+")))+
   QUOTIENT(SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, ":(\d+)"))), 60), 60)&":"&
   TEXT(MOD(SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\d+")))+
   QUOTIENT(SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, ":(\d+)"))), 60), 60), "00")&":"&
   TEXT(MOD(SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, ":(\d+)"))), 60), "00"))
  ```

  [image: 0]

  **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ib-DkXUIQo6KHG73AVchfCtIf-krP1HlorN9OwFhW4M/edit#gid=0)**

---

- **<sub>traces of how to get easily all links can be found here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/118383/186471</sub>**